# Maven Jar main class in src/main/resources

Tags: java, maven, testing, jar

I'm adding on a executable jar test to my maven project. I've edited my pom file to use a main class in src/main/resources. However when I try to run the jar it cannot find my main class. Any thoughts?

Comment: Added note, I have looked at the jar, and my main class is in the jar and I'm using the correct path to it..

Comment: The real question is...why should you put the main class into main/resources folder? Classes should stay in main/java folder, resources in main/resources...

Comment: I'm getting that, but this is just a testing program so I wanted it separate from the actual code. If its not possible thats fine, was just curious.

Comment: Can you see the compiled .class file in target/classes? I am not sure that .java files in src/main/resources get compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start your main class when you run `java -jar your-executable-jar.jar`, your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file should contain the [`Main-Class` header](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

```
Main-Class: con.example.YourClass
```

Maven can generate the manifest file with [`maven-jar-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your java classes should go in src/main/java.